# What if I can't find the jks file in Jar file on Spring JPA Gradle Project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, jwt

I am currently issuing a `Jwt` token. Currently, I am using `jks` file to issue and certify `Jwt` token. There are no problems with testing in the local environment.

However, converting to a `JAR` file results in an error that the `jks` file cannot be found. What's the reason?

I use `build.gradle` and `application.yml`.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.springboard.testing'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url = 'https://mvn.trabricks.io/content/repositories/m2/'
    }

    maven {
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }

    jcenter()

    maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }
}

bootJar {
    archiveBaseName = '-'
    archiveFileName = 'jinheeproject.jar'
    archiveVersion = "0.0.1"
}


 //resource 파일  바라보게 추가 
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources", "src/main/configs"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-maven-plugin', version: '2.2.5.RELEASE'


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'


    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.12.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.4.12.Final'

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:2.1.2.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.2.2.RELEASE'  
}
```

As you can see from my `build.gradle` file, I have set it to view the resource file. But the error doesn't change. I think it's hard to figure out what's wrong.

**error log**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot configure enpdoints
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.springboard.backend.Application.main(Application.java:21) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [jinheeproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [jinheeproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [jinheeproject.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [jinheeproject.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot configure enpdoints
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.init(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.java:81) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAccessTokenConverter' defined in class path resource [com/springboard/backend/config/Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]: Factory method 'jwtAccessTokenConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keys from store: file [/Users/username/git/springGradle/build/libs/src/main/resources/oauth2jwt.jks]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.springboard.backend.config.Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcf97348.jwtAccessTokenConverter(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.springboard.backend.config.Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.configure(Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java:96) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.init(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]: Factory method 'jwtAccessTokenConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keys from store: file [/Users/username/git/springGradle/build/libs/src/main/resources/oauth2jwt.jks]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keys from store: file [/Users/username/git/springGradle/build/libs/src/main/resources/oauth2jwt.jks]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.KeyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(KeyStoreKeyFactory.java:67) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.KeyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(KeyStoreKeyFactory.java:48) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at com.springboard.backend.config.Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtAccessTokenConverter(Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java:64) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.springboard.backend.config.Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcf97348.CGLIB$jwtAccessTokenConverter$3(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.springboard.backend.config.Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcf97348$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e9c01fa6.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.springboard.backend.config.Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcf97348.jwtAccessTokenConverter(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/oauth2jwt.jks
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:189) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.KeyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(KeyStoreKeyFactory.java:57) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

**file path**

[image]

**my use code**

```java
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/oauth2jwt.jks"), "oauth2jwtpass".toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("oauth2jwt"));
        return converter;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're receiving? What is the exact location of the resource file (not folder)?

Comment: @Jason Error details attached.

Comment: What is the exactly location of the resource file? Are you sure it's in src/main/resources

Comment: How are you trying to read the file? Post the code. This is very odd: /Users/taehong/git/springGradle/build/libs/src/main/resources/oauth2jwt.jks

I hope you're not using File/Path and instead using a Resource.

Comment: @Jason I added code

Comment: Ok, ive got a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by referring to Jason's link.

```java
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Value("classpath:oauth2jwt.jks")
Resource resourceFile;

@Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(resourceFile, "oauth2jwtpass".toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("oauth2jwt"));
        return converter;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem. You were using a FileSystemResource instead of ClassPathResource. Might be a compilation error, I didn't check. A CLassPathResource is necessary because you're accessing a file inside of a jar (sometimes) and not just a system file.

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access) could be helpful.

```java
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("oauth2jwt.jks", getClass().getClassLoader()), "oauth2jwtpass".toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("oauth2jwt"));
        return converter;
    }
```

Comment: An error occurs when tested in the local environment.